# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\django_extensions'

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

while "python manage.py runserver" it says ModuleNotFoundError but I have checked in the path  'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django_extensions' the django_extension exists and still it is giving error.
Just so you know i also tried pip install django_extensions it said installed successfully but when again i did "python manage.py runserver" it gave me the same error.... messed up right now....please help

settings.py file:-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
```

]

Comment: Have you added the `django_extentions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: yeah in Pycharm I have done it

Comment: You mean in the `settings.py` ?

Comment: While asking a question in the Stack Overflow, always try to add a code sample. In this case, add your code which you have used the `django_extentions` module and maybe `settings.py`

Comment: @Ramtin i have added settings.py INSTALLED_APPS.